# How to export/load data from azure blob storage (json format) to Pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, azure-storage, azure-application-insights

My data is stored in Azure blob storage in json format and i want to export/load the data into pandas dataframe with api if possible or any other method. No downloading of file

Is is possible to do so or is there any other method?

I havent been much successful in loading the data into pandas dataframe

Answer (score 0):

***I tried in my environment and got successfully loaded json files into dataframe format in python.***

**Code:**

```
from  azure.storage.blob  import  BlobServiceClient
import  json
import  json
import  pandas  as  pd
from  pandas  import  DataFrame
from  datetime  import  datetime
import  uuid

connect_str = "< connection string >"
blob_service_client = BlobServiceClient.from_connection_string(connect_str)
container_name="test"
 container_client=blob_service_client.get_container_client(container_name)
blob_list = container_client.list_blobs(name_starts_with="blob")
for  blob  in  blob_list:
print( )
blob_client = container_client.get_blob_client(blob)
streamdownloader = blob_client.download_blob()
fileReader = json.loads(streamdownloader.readall())
df = pd.DataFrame(fileReader)
print(df.head())
```

**Portal:**

In my blob storage I have an some of **`json`** files stored in the folder.
[image]

**Console**:

[image]

**Reference:**

[How to convert JSON into a Pandas DataFrame | by B. Chen | Towards Data Science](https://towardsdatascience.com/how-to-convert-json-into-a-pandas-dataframe-100b2ae1e0d8)

Comment: It doesnt print for me. Can you resend me your code with proper intedations

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: it is getting executed but no output for dataframe

Comment: Provide the snap of the output after execution of the above code provided and also check if you have any data present in json file.

Comment: JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 1640)

Idont know how to add images in the comment, but this is the error i am facing your code was right but still i am facing some rror with json file

Comment: Looks like your json file is not in correct and also refer this https://researchdatapod.com/how-to-solve-python-jsondecodeerror-extra-data/